# Is there any bug in Python strip() function?

Tags: python

Creating two strings:

```
s1 = "sha1:abcd"
s2 = "sha1:wxyz"
```

Applying `.strip()` function on both strings:

```
s1.strip("sha1:")
>>> 'bcd'

s2.strip("sha1:")
>>> 'wxyz'
```

I expected the following output:

```
s1.strip("sha1:")
>>> 'abcd'

s2.strip("sha1:")
>>> 'wxyz'
```

I am aware that `strip()` function is deprecated. I am just curious to know the issue. I went through official docs, but found no special mentions about ":a" or anything like that.

And also I am aware of other alternatives, we can use `split("sha1:")` or `strip("sha1")` followed by `strip(":")`, gives the desired output.

Comment: What output you are expecting?

Comment: Looks like he's expecting `s1.strip("sha1:")` to output `abcd` instead of `bcd`

Comment: I have added expected output.

Comment: method strip accept _set_ of characters, not a string prefix. Since char 'a' in this set 'sha1:', it stripped too.

Comment: The [`strip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) method of `str` objects is not deprecated. What is deprecated is calling the [`strip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip) function from the [`string`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) module.

Comment: You probably should be using `split(":")[1]` if you just want the right side

Comment: Before claiming that something that is used by people everyday is a bug, make sure to read its documentation. More often than not, you'll find you just assumed different behavior.

Comment: Before claiming, I thought to ask here. I went through documentation, but didn't find any relevant info.

Comment: Before asking, it is expected of you to do some level of research. [The documentation for `str.strip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) is pretty clear and also provides a somewhat relevant example.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

there

```
strip(...)
    S.strip([chars]) -> str

    Return a copy of the string S with leading and trailing
    whitespace removed.
    If chars is given and not None, remove characters in chars instead.
```

note **characters in chars**

Explained in detail in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip).

Comment: To clarify, it is stripping *any* of the characters from `chars`, meaning any s's, h's, a's, etc..

Answer (score 1):

It will strip all characters i.e. `s`, `h`, `a` , `1` and `:` at the beginning and ending of the string.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a counter example showing the *actual* intention of `strip`:

```
s1 = "sha1:abcds"
s2 = "sha1:wxyzs"

print(s1.strip("sha1:"))
print(s2.strip("sha1:"))
```

Output:

```
bcd
wxyz
```

`strip()` removed chars supplied in its parameter, whether they are found at the start or end of the target.

Comment: Not if they are in the middle...

Comment: Yeah, ;-) updated answer.